# how to return number of rows in table for the current id using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to return the number of drivers assigned to the current vehicle. In database terms, that would be the number of rows in the table for the current Id.
For now i have this piece of code

```
var driversArray = [{ QuoteDriverId: '5967', QuoteVehicleId: '5486', AssignmentType:'Principal', PercentUse: '100' },
                    { QuoteDriverId: '5968', QuoteVehicleId: '5487',
AssignmentType: 'Principal', PercentUse: '100' },
                    { QuoteDriverId: '5969', QuoteVehicleId: '5488',
AssignmentType: 'Principal', PercentUse: '100'},
                    { QuoteDriverId: '5970', QuoteVehicleId: '5489',
AssignmentType: 'Principal', PercentUse: '100' }];

        var paramQuoteVehicleId = 0;
        var NumAssignedDrivers = 0;

        if (driversArray) {

            for (var q = 0; q < driversArray.length; q++) {
                if (driversArray[q].QuoteVehicleId === paramQuoteVehicleId)
                    NumAssignedDrivers++;
            }
        }
        return NumAssignedDrivers;
```

Comment: can you please explain what DB you are using and how you are accessing it. right now all you have is that array, but you want more, am I right?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I need to return the number of rows in the QuoteDriverAssignments table for the current QuoteVehicleId.

Comment: I represented QuoteDriverAssignments table as an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your code to look nicer, you can use Array.filter method to extract a subset of your data matching your query:

```
var result = driversArray.filter(
    function (value) {
        return (value.QuoteVehicleId === paramQuoteVehicleId)
    }
);

NumAssignedDrivers = result.length
```